# Over sampling imbalance data in SVM

Tags: sampling, svm, prediction, libsvm

Basically I have a medium size data set (20,000 observations) with only 200 being in group 1, thus an imbalanced data set. My goal is to predict as much group 1 class as possible without sacrificing too much false positive.

With some research, I understand putting `class.weight = c('1'=100,'0'=0.5)` in `svm()` would be a method to specify different misclassification  penalty for groups. Over sampling the minority group or subset the majority group would also be solutions to the data imbalance. However, I am not sure how the latter would help the situation because the prediction proportion for positive should ultimately be small even the training data set is "balanced."

So my question would be the following:

1) When using over sampling the minority class, how would I adjust the prediction (or the model) so the prediction will ensure only a small proportions are assigned to be class 1?

2) During the fitting for `svm()` with the original data, how should I specify the value `cost` ? I could tune it with `tune()` but the running time increase tremendously after I put `class.weight=c('1'=100,'0'=0.5)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Using SMOTE method to oversample would make a better classification on future prediction even the training data set doesn't consist of balanced result.

2) The `class.weight` argument in `svm()` doesn't perform well, one could use SMOTE or other method to create a balanced data instead of using `weight` argument. Alternatively, using a tree `rpart` might be a option where it can specify the loss matrix.